Azure Devops not pulling the latest build artifact from the branch that I passed in using a variable
When I run this pipeline in Azure Devops, it doesn't pull in the latest build from the master branch.
Here's what I have:
resources:
 pipelines: 
 - pipeline: My-Pipeline
   source: My-Source
   trigger: none
   branch: ${{variables.MainBranch}}

variables:
 - name: MainBranch
   value: 'refs/heads/master'

I also have a validation job that compares the value of the MainBranch variable to the source branch metadata variable, resources.pipeline.My-Pipeline.sourceBranch. This job succeeds, but when I check the consumed artifacts in ADO it shows that it wasn't pulled from master or it was pulled from master but not the most recent build.
